# Compare two different child nodes from two different parent nodes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare two different child nodes from two different parent nodes. The JSON structure is the following: `Attending Event > postId > userId` and the second one is structured as follows: `Following > firebaseUserId > userId`. The goal here is to compare the `userId's` and if I am following that `userId` and also that person / `userId` *IS* attending the event, then I want to populate a list with those users.

I already wrote two methods, one to get the users that I am following `getFollowing();` and another to get the users that are attending the event `getAttendingEvent();`. Is there a way to compare the `lists / usersIds` from the two methods I have already written, or do I have to write a new method entirely?

I´m really not sure how to go about this… Am I on the right track with the `getFriendsAttendingEvent();` method I just wrote?

**FollowersActivity**

```
public class FollowersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String mId;
    String mTitle;
    String mPostId;

    List<String> mIdList;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    List<User> mUserList;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_followers);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        mTitle = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        mPostId = intent.getStringExtra("postid");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(this, mUserList, false);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);

        mIdList = new ArrayList<>();

        switch (mTitle) {
            case "Likes":
                getLikes();
                break;
            case "Following":
                getFollowing();
                break;
            case "Followers":
                getFollowers();
                break;
            case "Attending Event":
                getAttendingEvent();
            case "Friends Attending":
                // Create this method
        }
    }

    private void getFriendsAttendingEvent(List<User> userList, List<User> userList1) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Events").child(mPostId);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                userList.add(user);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Following").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
    reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user1 = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                userList1.add(user1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // Compare the two lists user's somehow..
    if (userList.equals(userList1)) {
        showUsers();
    }
}

    private void getLikes() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Likes").child(mPostId);
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mIdList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mIdList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                showUsers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getAttendingEvent() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event").child(mPostId);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mIdList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mIdList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                showUsers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getFollowing() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Following").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mIdList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mIdList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                showUsers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getFollowers() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Followers").child(mId);
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mIdList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mIdList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                showUsers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showUsers() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUserList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    for (String id : mIdList) {
                        if (user != null)
                            if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                                mUserList.add(user);
                            }
                    }
                }

                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi man, you can try debug mode. Add breakpoint to two for loops and if clause. You can see the problem.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir hey Kasim, I need to declare the ```getFriendsAttendingEvent();``` method in onCreate, but I have ```userList``` and ```userList1``` as parameters, and when I declare it what do I pass ```getFriendsAttendingEvent();``` in onCreate? I can debug it, but first I have to declare it, right?

Comment: Right, you have to declare it before. You send two empty lists then you can debug.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir like this or something? ```getFriendsAttendingEvent(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.EMPTY_LIST);```? Or is that wrong?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I tried it like that, but it crashed on this line ```userList1.add(user1);``` says unsupportedOperationsException...

Comment: getFriendsAttendingEvent(new ArrayList< User >(),new ArrayList< User >())  is enough for you.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir so the problem is their size userList and userList1 is 0 is what it's showing me...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213873/discussion-between-kasim-ozdemir-and-jmb).

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir was wondering, for the method we worked on yesterday, I need to obtain the size of the list, but the method we wrote yesterday we wrote in the FollowersActivity and the ViewHolder is in the PostAdapter class, so how can I share the size of the list or transfer the information from ```mIdList1``` with the number of users to PostAdapter?